# Python implementation for connected components labeling for arrays creates wrong results

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, connected-components

This is my implementation of the connected components algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling).
What is the reason for my wrong results?
Where is my mistake and how can I fix it?
I appreciate any ideas!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
import numpy as np


def resolve_equivalent_labels_dict(input_dict, labels):
    # merge lists
    for key in reversed(input_dict.keys()):
        input_dict[key] = list(set(sorted(input_dict[key])))
        for key2, lis2 in input_dict.items():
            if key != key2 and key in lis2:
                input_dict[key2].extend(input_dict[key])
                input_dict[key] = []
    
    # Fix problem, where a label is part of multiple lists.
    for label_i in labels:
        key_list = []
        for key, lis in input_dict.items():
            if label_i in lis:
                key_list.append(key)
        if len(key_list) > 1:
            key_list.remove(min(key_list))
            for key in key_list:
                input_dict[key].remove(label_i)
    
    for key in input_dict.keys():
        if input_dict[key] == []:
            input_dict.pop(key)
        else:
            input_dict[key] = sorted(list(set(input_dict[key])))
    return input_dict


def CCL(arr):
    # Write labels
    offsets = [(0,-1),(-1,0),(-1,-1),(-1,1)]
    equivalent_labels = {}
    current_label = 1
    labels = [current_label]
    for row_i in range(len(arr)):
        for col_i in range(len(arr[0])):
            if arr[row_i, col_i] == 1:
                
                # Read labels from neighbors
                vals_neighbors = []
                for (row_off, col_off) in offsets:
                    v = arr[row_i+row_off, col_i+col_off]
                    if v != 0:
                        vals_neighbors.append(v)

                # Write labels and fill equivalent_label dict
                if len(vals_neighbors) == 0: # no neighbor, new label
                    current_label+=1
                    labels.append(current_label)
                    equivalent_labels[current_label] = []
                    arr[row_i, col_i] = current_label
                elif len(vals_neighbors) == 1: # one neighbor
                    arr[row_i, col_i] = vals_neighbors[0]
                elif len(vals_neighbors) > 1: # multiple neighbors
                    vals_neighbors = list(set(vals_neighbors))
                    first = min(vals_neighbors)
                    vals_neighbors.remove(first)
                    arr[row_i, col_i] = first
                    if first in equivalent_labels.keys():
                        equivalent_labels[first].extend(vals_neighbors)
                    else:
                        equivalent_labels[first] = vals_neighbors

    # Merge lists
    print(equivalent_labels)    
    equivalent_labels = resolve_equivalent_labels_dict(equivalent_labels, labels)
    print("")
    print(equivalent_labels)  

    # Rename labels
    for key in reversed(equivalent_labels.keys()):   
        lis = list(np.unique(equivalent_labels[key]))
        for elem in lis:
            arr = np.where(arr == elem, key, arr)

    return arr
                

# create data
gridlength = 20
input_array = np.zeros((gridlength+2, gridlength+2))
input_array[1:gridlength+1, 1:1+gridlength] = np.random.randint(2, size=(gridlength,gridlength))
print(input_array)

# Plot
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20,10))
ax1.pcolormesh(input_array, cmap=colors.ListedColormap(["white", "red"]))
output_array = CCL(input_array)
output_array[output_array==0] == np.nan
ax2.pcolormesh(output_array)
ax1.set_xlim([0,gridlength+2])
ax2.set_xlim([0,gridlength+2])
ax1.set_ylim([0,gridlength+2])
ax2.set_ylim([0,gridlength+2])
for (j,i),label in np.ndenumerate(output_array):
    ax2.text(i,j,int(label),ha='center',va='center')
plt.savefig("code/connectivity/ccl.png", dpi=300, bbox_inches="tight")
```

with `input_array` as

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

gives this result where you can see that "3" and "5" areas are not merged: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B30XV.png)

Comment: Please post minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you want to implement this from scratch? There are implementations in `scipy` and `skimage` that will do this for you, where you can also define the connectivity.

- [`scipy.ndimage.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html)
- [`skimage.measure.label`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#label)

Example using the `scipy` implementation.

```py
import numpy as np
from ast import literal_eval
import re

from scipy.ndimage import label
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Working jupyterlab so enable plotting in the notebook.
%matplotlib inline

# Transforming your pasted output into a usable array
raw_data = """
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.],
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.],
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0.],
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0.],
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.],
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0.],
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0.],
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.],
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.],
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.],
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.],
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.],
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.],
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.],
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.],
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0.],
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.],
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.],
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.],
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.],
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0.],
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
"""

input_array = np.array(literal_eval(re.sub("\.", ",", raw_data))).astype(float)

# label returns the labelled array and the number of components created
component_array, num_components = label(input_array, structure=np.ones((3,3)))

print(num_components)
# 4

# I had to vertical flip your input data to get it to display how it was in your expected result figure.
plt.imshow(np.flipud(component_array))
```

[image: connected components]

I haven't really answered your question, but you might want to consider an implementation that already exists if you were not aware of them yet.